# Using Amazon ElastiCache redis for storing sessions

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

What is the best configuration for redis Cache Cluster to use it for storing sessions?

If I just use one node, how often it could fail and all data could lost?

I want session lifetime ~14 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use multiple nodes for session data.  Although we only experienced one outage over a year ago in US-East, why risk it?